# Page transitions for slow page load silverlight Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, transition, pageload

I have a silverlight page with around 250 elements on it. The page load time is around 2.5 seconds on average. I have tried to cut down on the data part, but I don't think it helps that much. 
Even loading without any data takes around 2 seconds. I'm guessing it's the UI elements load time that cause the slowness.

my current navigation structure is:

app load --- main page --- game page.

The problem is in the game page load time. other pages loads very snappily.

the current "slowness" happens when I press the navigating button (start game button), and the app freeze, and then load the next page.

my questions are: is there anyway to "pre-load" the page? failing that, is there anyway to run some sort of animation for the perception of snappiness?

I tried page transition based on silverlight toolkit, but I don't think it helps at all. the animation starts after the "freezing" after navigation button is pressed.

thanks

Alvin

Answer (score 0):

If the app appears to "freeze" then you are performing a long-running task (in processor cycle terms) on the UI thread, which you should be able to offload onto a background thread to let the page load quicker. If you are using the WP 7.1 SDK tools and targeting Mango, then you can use the built-in performance analysis tools to locate the source of the bottleneck.